# Cloning SVN project

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

This is a very basic question in SVN:

I want to download Google's BreakPad project. In their site they say to do:

> Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP. svn checkout http://google-breakpad.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-breakpad-read-only

When I try to download this project with TortoiseSVN all I can do is download the trunk branch (using only http://google-breakpad.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)

How can I download the `google-breakpad-read-only` revision/branch?

Thank you from a Git user

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you'd like to achieve. Looking at their website, there are some branches (http://google-breakpad.googlecode.com/svn/branches/) but which one you want to have? Then just replace the URL by the one you want to download.

Comment: I just want to follow their instruction here https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/checkout

Comment: You've done that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `google-breakpad-read-only` in the instructions above is the `working folder` that the trunk will end up in on your machine. (The `google-breakpad-read-only` folder of whatever drive you're exploring when you invoke the checkout.) There is no `google-breakpoint-read-only` revision/branch.)

It's the folder name of the working copy (destination). You can replace it with `svn checkout http://google-breakpad.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ my-dog-and-cat` and end up with a working copy in your `my-dog-and-cat` folder.